# Get count from MySQL table which added on or before a date and deleted on or after a date

Tags: mysql, select, date-comparison

I am very much new to SQL and I don't know much

TABLE `employee_table` contains the following columns

```
`pkId` INT(10),
`name` VARCHAR(60),
`pfStatus` TINYINT(3),
`is_active` TINYINT(3),
`addedDate` DATE,
`deletedDate` DATE
```

And an entry is there with the given values

> pkId = 1, name = abhips, pfStatus = 0, is_active = 1, addedDate = 2012-08-08, deletedDate = 2012-08-18

-

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee_table WHERE pfStatus = 0 AND addedDate >= '2012-07-07' AND deletedDate <= '2012-08-09';

I want to get the number of employees who are registered on or before a particular date and deleted on or after a particular date and pfStatus = 0.

But I am getting the count as 0 instead of 1 , please help me with this query, What are the changes to be made to get this query correct ?

Comment: Are you counting an employee who registered on/before a particular date as well as an employee who was deleted after a particular date?  Or are you including an employee who both registered on/before a date AND was deleted after a certain date?

Comment: @HolgerBrandt , Second case : An employeewho both registered on/before a date AND was deleted after a particular date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<=` and `>=` are the wrong way around.

> I want to get the number of employees who are **registered on or before** a particular date and **deleted on or after** a particular date and pfStatus = 0.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM employee_table
WHERE pfStatus = 0
AND addedDate <= '2012-07-07'
AND deletedDate >= '2012-08-09';
```

Comment: +1 Note: he will still get a count of 0, as the sample data `added_date` does not meet the `WHERE` clause conditions.

Comment: @Mark Byers, Thank you for your reply but as  RedFilter said I'm still getting the value 0

Comment: @abhips: He also explained why... your data doesn't match the conditions. Your problem is not that the query is incorrect. You have bad test data.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the employees who will have been active in the period between 2012-07-07 - 2012-08-09.

**SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM employee_table

WHERE pfStatus = 0

AND addedDate <= '2012-08-09'

AND deletedDate >= '2012-07-07';**